# Most common letter ( Capital and small) in a string

Tags: java, string

I want to write down some method that receive a string and return me the most common letter in small version.(only letters)
For example - "aabbbAA" will return a.
"766&%- aabbB" will return b.

I tried to write it down but i don't know how to recognize between Capital letters and small letters.
And how to recognize between digits and letters.

JAVA

Thank ;)

Comment: what program language do you use?

Comment: Java, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] counters = new int['z' - 'a' + 1];
    for( int i = 0; i < counters.length; i++ ) {
        counters[i] = 0;
    }

    String str = new String("absgsAAAAs");
    for( int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++ ) {
        if( str.charAt( i ) >= 'a' && str.charAt( i ) <= 'z' ) {
            counters[str.charAt( i ) - 'a']++;
        } else if( str.charAt( i ) >= 'A' && str.charAt( i ) <= 'Z' ) {
            counters[str.charAt( i ) - 'A']++;
        }
    }

    int maxi = 0;
    for( int i = 1; i < counters.length; i++ ) {
        if( counters[i] > counters[maxi] ) {
            maxi = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println( Character.toChars( 'a' + maxi ) );
```

Comment: I have to count the Capital and the small letters Together. For example ''aaAAbbb'' will return me 'a'.